# How to optimize the following oracle query to get the from and to country name in one join only?

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the query I am trying to run.

```
    select 
          from_country_id, 
          to_country_id, 
          fromCountry.country_name as from_country_name, 
          to_country_id.country_name as to_country_name
    from TourDetails t 
    left join country fromCountry on fromCountry.id = t. from_country_id
    left join country toCountry on toCountry.id = t. to_country_id
```

I have a tourdetails table where i save the from country id and to country id. I have another country table which has the country id and country name.

now when i query the tourdetails table I need to get the country name as well. For this I am using left join with the countyry table twice.

Is there any way I do not have to join this country table twice and still get the country name for both the from and to country?

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović. So this is how I will have to do it? I mean the way I have done it.

Comment: Yes. This is one of the reasons we have table aliases.

Comment: And there is no reason not to join twice based on your requirement. The only alternative I can think of would be to write two functions, GetFromCountry(TourDetails.ID) and GetToCountry(TourDetails.ID). Each function would take the country name from the IDs in the TourDetails table. Probably more trouble than it's worth in this case though.

Comment: @Tobsey. The reason I was trying for some better solution was I will have few more (in fact 7 to 8) other tables like country which I will need to left join to get their names e.g. Region (from and to), Agent (from and to) etc.

Comment: Won't it make query slow if I have so many joins?

Comment: Why are you using left joins instead of inner joins? I would expect the foreign keys in TourDetails to be constrained to refer to actual entries in the country table.

Comment: @Walter Mitty. yes, It should be inner join.

Comment: Inner joins sometimes run much faster than left joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to retrieving country details (name) based on tuple ( [from, to] in tour).

As far as I know it's possible to do with `exists`. Please take a look if one below works for you.

Schema:

```
create table country (
  country_id varchar2(10)
);

create table tour
(
  from_country_id varchar2(10),
  to_country_id varchar2(10)
);
```

Data:

```
insert into country select 'AU' from dual;
insert into country select 'UA' from dual;
insert into country select 'UK' from dual;

insert into tour select 'AU', 'UA'  from dual;
insert into tour select 'UK', 'UA'  from dual;
insert into tour select 'UA', 'AU'  from dual;
```

Solution itself:

```
select
  country_from.country_id from_, 
  country_to.country_id to_ 
from 
  country country_from,
  country country_to
where exists
  (select
     from_country_id, 
     to_country_id
   from tour 
   where 
     from_country_id = country_from.country_id 
    and 
     to_country_id = country_to.country_id)
```

No inner joins needed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can not optimize the query it migh possible to optimize the execution of the query.
You should check the explain plan of the query and if it is using nested loop, it might worth to force hash by `/*+USE_HASH(country) */`

Comment: Sorry I did not get what you are trying to say? :(

Comment: Oracle optimizer creates a plan how to run the sql script. In some cases the optimizer uses a wrong stategy, but you can override it by adding hints to the sql. More on the explain plan: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm

Comment: @ZoltanHamori I think it's a little premature to start thinking about hints.  (And also, you'd need to use the table alias, not the actual table name.)

Answer (score 0):

Inner Joins sometimes run much faster than Left Joins.  An inner join and a left join will yield the same results in situations where referential integrity has been enforced on the data.  Referential integrity means that every instance of a foreign key refers to an existing row in the referenced table.

Referential integrity can be enforced by the DBMS via declared constraints in the data definitions.  An alternative that sometimes works is to enforce referential integrity in the process that loads new data.  Having the DBMS enforce referential integrity is usually preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one join, at the expense of having an `or` (or `in`) in the join condition and code that is arguably less clear:

```
select t.from_country_id,
    t.to_country_id,
    max(case when c.id = from_country_id then c.country_name end)
        as from_country_name,
    max(case when c.id = to_country_id then c.country_name end)
        as to_country_name
from tourdetails t
join country c on c.id = t.from_country_id or c.id = t.to_country_id
group by t.from_country_id, t.to_country_id;
```

There may not be much performance difference between this and having two joins, you'd need to test to check. Depends what you mean by 'optimize' in this instance. I guess it's probably more a matter if style here - trading off reducing the number of joins against more complicated manipulation of the returned data.